# Milky fluid inside chicken

Tags: food-safety

I cooked a 5lb chicken at 350 for 2 1/2 hours. When we cut one side it was nice n white with clear juices. The other side had a milky fluid in it. What is it, caused it, and is it safe to eat?

Comment: Any foul odors? Do you know when the meat was butchered or packed?

Comment: It is quite possibly just coagulated albumin; did you get a picture?

Comment: How strange. Method of cooking? When you said milky white fluid the first thing I thought of was the fatty water that clouds up when you boil a chicken. Personally I recommend quartering a chicken before you roast it. Oh--and welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that's a combination of protein/fat/liquid that coagulates when you cook the chicken. Was it the lower half of the chicken that had this liquid?

And if that is indeed what it is, it's safe to eat. It doesn't taste very good though, so I wouldn't recommend trying it.

Comment: If it was a commercially-raised chicken, chances are good that the white fluid is a result of the use of antibiotics and chemical feeds. Most of my insides were damaged some years ago by a five-week battle with antibiotic-resistant e-coli, and since then, if I eat feeds that have too many chemicals and the like, my right-side kidney tells me about it. Chicken that produces that milky liquid invariably leave me in a great deal of pain.